# How to horizontally center align content in semantic Grid row?

Tags: css, reactjs, semantic-ui

I am trying to center content for one of my columns in Semantic grid. It is giving me the output I need but I want to know if there is a way to achieve the same result without using the two "<Grid.Column tablet={3} computer={3}/>" tags. Below is my code. Thanks

```
<Grid style={{ height: "100vh"}} padded>
  <Grid.Row>
      <Grid.Column tablet={2} computer={2} stretched>
        <Main activePage={"Add Department"} />
      </Grid.Column>
      <Grid.Column tablet={3} computer={3}/>
      <Grid.Column tablet={8} computer={8} verticalAlign={"middle"}>
        <Header as="h2" textAlign="center">
          Department
        </Header>
        <Divider section />
        <Form>
          <FormInput 
          headerText={"Name"}
          onChange={value => {
            value != "" ? setFormErrors(false) : setFormErrors(true) 
            setDepartmentName(value)
            }
          }/>
        </Form>
        <Divider section />
        <Button color="blue" fluid size="large" onClick={SaveForm}>
          Save
        </Button>
        {Messages()}
      </Grid.Column>
      <Grid.Column tablet={3} computer={3}/>
    </Grid.Row>
</Grid>
```